# Apollo useLazyQuery hook uses old variables when refetching (instead of new vars)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

My database stores a list of items. I've written a query to randomly return one item from the list each time a button is clicked. I use useLazyQuery and call the returned function to execute the query and it works fine. I can call the refetch function on subsequent button presses and it returns another random item correctly.

The problem comes when i try to pass variables to the query. I want to provide different criteria to the query to tailor how the random choice is made. Whatever variables I pass to the first call are repeated on each refetch, even though they have changed. I can trace that they are different on the client but the resolver traces the previous variables.

```
// My query
const PICK = gql`
  query Pick($options: PickOptionsInput) {
    pick(options: $options) {
      title
    }
  }
`;

// My lazy hook
const [pick, { data, refetch }] = useLazyQuery(PICK, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  });


// My button
<MyButton
  onPick={(options) =>
     (refetch || pick)({ // Refetch unless this is the first click, then pick
         variables: {
            options      // Options is a custom object of data used to control the pick
         },
     })
  }
/>
```

Some things I've tried:

- Various cache policies
- Not using an object for the options and defining each possible option as a different variable

I'm really stumped. It seems like the docs say new variables are supposed to be used if they are provided on refetch. I don't think the cache policy is relevant...I'm getting fresh results on each call, it's just the input variables that are stale.

Comment: Did you try with the `fetch-policy` = `network-only` also please share your code that how you are getting options

Comment: if *'they are different on the client'* (checked on network request body?) then simply not a client problem?

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash The options are passed to the "onPick" handler i posted. I can trace it there right before I call the lazy query and see that the values in the "options" object are changing correctly. For example, depending on the button i pick, it might be { minimum: 5000 } or { minimum: 4000, maximum: 8000 }. I can see these update correctly but no matter what they are, the value i trace out in my resolver will always be whatever the options were on the first call to the lazy query.

Comment: @xadm The variables in the request payload are always whatever they were on the first call to the lazy query. I can trace them out on the client right before calling the lazy query function and they will change, but by the time the request goes out, they are the same as what was sent on the first call. So the issue seems to be that passing new values into the lazy query function has no effect.

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash I have tried all cache policies. They have do the correct things regarding the -responses- get back (in other words, no-cache causes a new request, cache-first just gets the cached response). The issue is the variables sent to the server are "stuck" despite being different when they are passed to the lazy function.

Answer (score 2):

I guess only `pick` is called ...

... because for `<MyBytton/>` there is no props change, no `onPick` redefined - always the first handler definition used (from first render) and `options` state from the same time ...

Try to pass all (`options`, `pick` and `refetch`) as direct props to force rerendering and handler redefinition:

```
<MyButton
  options={options}
  pick={pick}
  refetch={refetch}
  onPick={(options) =>
     (refetch || pick)({ // Refetch unless this is the first click, then pick
         variables: {
            options      // Options is a custom object of data used to control the pick
         },
     })
  }
/>
```

... or [better] define handler before passing it into `<MyButton/>`:

```
const pickHandler = useCallback( 
  (options) => {
     if(refetch) {
       console.log('refetch', options);
       refetch( { variables: { options }});
     } else {
       console.log('pick', options);
       pick( { variables: { options }});
     }
  },
  [options, pick, refetch]
);

<MyButton onPick={pickHandler} />
```

Comment: I can't do this because I don't have the options until the button is clicked. That's why i'm using the lazy handler. The app can re-render many times before 'onPick' fires.

Comment: ... and this is exactly what you need (and `useCallback` was designed for) ... handler updated only on dependency change (not on every render) - `options` is in dependency, will be actual when required ... just try, log will tell the truth